# Workarounds for "Missing required dependencies ['numpy'] Traceback "

Tags: python, numpy

I am on a Windows box and I had created pandas and numpy dependencies but I needed to have a colleague build them correctly  using a Linux box and adding that to my Lambda for another project. The lambda is larger than 10 M so it needs to be uploaded via S3.
This lambda works with no dependency errors.

Here is what I am including:

```
import boto3
import json
import decimal
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime
from os import urandom
import email
import base64
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import mailparser
import calendar
```

However when I have a colleague add these dependencies along with my lambda function I get

> Missing required dependencies ['numpy'] Traceback
> error.
>
> Q) Can I copy the  pandas and numpy dependencies from the previous
> lamba file that is working well and add it to my new lambda_function.py
> file?

Here is a screen shot of what my colleague is including. Thanks:

[image]

Comment: Maybe try using serverless framework to do the packaging for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I wound up having to do to solve this:
After asking my Network Admin ,

1. he created a Python VM on Linux server and we tried to bundle numpy with the lambda into a zip file.
2. Then we uploaded the zip file to AWS.
3. When S3 bucket ingestion still failed, I made a copy of another lambda source file that contained numpy.
4. I gutted that lambda file copy and replaced its contents with my new project code and packaged everything into a zip to upload to AWS Lambda.

It works just fine though I wish the python VM would've have done the trick because I could always refer to bundling library dependencies with my lambda using python VM on the Linux server with the latest libraries than scavenging files.
Desperate times call for desperate measures.